# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Site Warmup

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I've migrated a .NET Framework 4.6 WebApi to .NETCore 2.2 and am having trouble getting the IIS ApplicationInitialization module to call my endpoints on a startup/slot swap/scale out.

I added a Web.Config like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\FR911.Api.Core.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />

      <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
        <add initializationPage="api/Warmup>
        <add initializationPage="/" />
      </applicationInitialization>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

But if I keep the default hosting model of "inprocess" my warmup never gets called.  If I change to "outofprocess" hosting, my warmup does get called before the swap is completed.

I think the issue below is likely related:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8057

I'm not looking to just manually ping or otherwise hit my endpoint because I want the existing feature in the module that IIS is Azure won't actually swap the endpoints until the warmup requests have finished (thus initing EFCore etc.)

Has anyone had any luck getting this to work with the inprocess hosting model?

Comment: Please refer below link, hopefully it will help you. https://michaelcandido.com/app-service-warm-up-demystified/

Comment: The post by @Ravi is a good one overall, especially with respect to details of how AppInit works in Azure. I don't know that it addresses the specific problem you're having, but good info in general. One interesting thing I noticed in at the bottom of the Github issue you posted - is Windows Authentication enabled for your app?